# An error in deploying shiny app to Shinyapps.io

Tags: r, shiny, dplyr

I have a Shiny app that uses the following packages in the `server.R` file.

```
library(shiny)      #Creating the app 
library(ggplot2)    
library(plyr)       
library(reshape2)
library(scales)
library(grid)
library(data.table)
library(pracma)
library(dplyr)
```

The app runs without any errors inside Rstudio; however, it gave an error (below) when I tried to upload it. It seems that the error is related to the `dplyr` package. It uploads successfully when I remove the `dplyr` package. I need the `dplyr` and `plyr` package to do some calculations in the `server.R` script.

N.B. The scripts for `server.R` and `ui.R` are very long and hard to include  in the question here.

Is there anybody who had similar issue? What is the thing that is going wrong here and how can I deal with it?

Here is the errror that I've got in Rstudio upon uploading the Shiny app:

```
library(rsconnect)
library(shinyapps)
deployApp()
Preparing to deploy application...DONE
Uploading application bundle...DONE
Deploying application: 62376...
Waiting for task: 84820935
  building: Parsing manifest
  building: Building package: dplyr
################################## Begin Log ################################## 
[2015-09-28T13:03:38.472015516+0000] Installing R package: stringr (0.6.2)
* installing to library ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
* installing *binary* package ‘stringr’ ...
* DONE (stringr)
[2015-09-28T13:03:38.776647291+0000] Installing R package: xtable (1.7-4)
* installing to library ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
* installing *binary* package ‘xtable’ ...
* DONE (xtable)
[2015-09-28T13:03:39.154920707+0000] Installing R package: magrittr (1.5)
* installing to library ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
* installing *binary* package ‘magrittr’ ...
* DONE (magrittr)
[2015-09-28T13:03:39.452820158+0000] Installing R package: labeling (0.3)
* installing to library ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
* installing *binary* package ‘labeling’ ...
* DONE (labeling)
[2015-09-28T13:03:39.739944987+0000] Installing R package: assertthat (0.1)
* installing to library ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
* installing *binary* package ‘assertthat’ ...
* DONE (assertthat)
[2015-09-28T13:03:40.033778274+0000] Installing R package: R6 (2.0.1)
* installing to library ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
* installing *binary* package ‘R6’ ...
* DONE (R6)
[2015-09-28T13:03:40.357424887+0000] Installing R package: RColorBrewer (1.1-2)
* installing to library ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
* installing *binary* package ‘RColorBrewer’ ...
* DONE (RColorBrewer)
[2015-09-28T13:03:40.691238121+0000] Installing R package: lazyeval (0.1.10)
* installing to library ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
* installing *binary* package ‘lazyeval’ ...
* DONE (lazyeval)
[2015-09-28T13:03:41.003724500+0000] Installing R package: proto (0.3-10)
* installing to library ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
* installing *binary* package ‘proto’ ...
* DONE (proto)
[2015-09-28T13:03:41.332937285+0000] Installing R package: dichromat (2.0-0)
* installing to library ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
* installing *binary* package ‘dichromat’ ...
* DONE (dichromat)
[2015-09-28T13:03:41.633100045+0000] Installing R package: digest (0.6.8)
* installing to library ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
* installing *binary* package ‘digest’ ...
* DONE (digest)
[2015-09-28T13:03:41.944605574+0000] Installing R package: mime (0.3)
* installing to library ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
* installing *binary* package ‘mime’ ...
* DONE (mime)
[2015-09-28T13:03:42.239146786+0000] Installing R package: BH (1.58.0-1)
* installing to library ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
* installing *binary* package ‘BH’ ...
* DONE (BH)
[2015-09-28T13:03:59.669982393+0000] Installing R package: htmltools (0.2.6)
* installing to library ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
* installing *binary* package ‘htmltools’ ...
* DONE (htmltools)
[2015-09-28T13:03:59.948658888+0000] Installing R package: gtable (0.1.2)
* installing to library ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
* installing *binary* package ‘gtable’ ...
* DONE (gtable)
[2015-09-28T13:04:00.234956933+0000] Installing R package: pracma (1.8.6)
* installing to library ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
* installing *binary* package ‘pracma’ ...
* DONE (pracma)
[2015-09-28T13:04:00.571098497+0000] Installing R package: MASS (7.3-39)
* installing to library ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
* installing *binary* package ‘MASS’ ...
* DONE (MASS)
[2015-09-28T13:04:00.952481970+0000] Installing R package: chron (2.3-45)
* installing to library ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
* installing *binary* package ‘chron’ ...
* DONE (chron)
[2015-09-28T13:04:01.233753667+0000] Installing R package: DBI (0.3.1)
* installing to library ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
* installing *binary* package ‘DBI’ ...
* DONE (DBI)
[2015-09-28T13:04:01.513957352+0000] Installing R package: colorspace (1.2-6)
* installing to library ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
* installing *binary* package ‘colorspace’ ...
* DONE (colorspace)
[2015-09-28T13:04:01.831425825+0000] Installing R package: munsell (0.4.2)
* installing to library ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
* installing *binary* package ‘munsell’ ...
* DONE (munsell)
[2015-09-28T13:04:02.126041041+0000] Installing R package: RJSONIO (1.3-0)
* installing to library ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
* installing *binary* package ‘RJSONIO’ ...
* DONE (RJSONIO)
[2015-09-28T13:04:02.618250623+0000] Installing R package: Rcpp (0.11.5)
* installing to library ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
* installing *binary* package ‘Rcpp’ ...
* DONE (Rcpp)
[2015-09-28T13:04:04.152878468+0000] Installing R package: plyr (1.8.1)
* installing to library ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
* installing *binary* package ‘plyr’ ...
* DONE (plyr)
[2015-09-28T13:04:04.539795069+0000] Installing R package: reshape2 (1.4.1)
* installing to library ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
* installing *binary* package ‘reshape2’ ...
* DONE (reshape2)
[2015-09-28T13:04:04.862150499+0000] Installing R package: data.table (1.9.4)
* installing to library ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
* installing *binary* package ‘data.table’ ...
* DONE (data.table)
[2015-09-28T13:04:05.262569153+0000] Installing R package: scales (0.2.4)
* installing to library ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
* installing *binary* package ‘scales’ ...
* DONE (scales)
[2015-09-28T13:04:05.545724339+0000] Installing R package: ggplot2 (1.0.1)
* installing to library ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
* installing *binary* package ‘ggplot2’ ...
* DONE (ggplot2)
[2015-09-28T13:04:06.026664262+0000] Installing R package: httpuv (1.3.2)
* installing to library ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
* installing *binary* package ‘httpuv’ ...
* DONE (httpuv)
[2015-09-28T13:04:06.457687110+0000] Installing R package: shiny (0.11.1)
* installing to library ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
* installing *binary* package ‘shiny’ ...
* DONE (shiny)
[2015-09-28T13:04:07.205284969+0000] Building R package: dplyr (0.4.3)
/mnt/packages/build /mnt
* installing to library ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
* installing *source* package ‘dplyr’ ...
** package ‘dplyr’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
Error: package ‘Rcpp’ 0.11.5 was found, but >= 0.12.0 is required by ‘dplyr’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/dplyr’
################################### End Log ################################### 
Error: Unhandled Exception: Child Task 84820936 failed: Error building image: Error building dplyr (0.4.3). Build exited with non-zero status: 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution for my problem. The `dplyr` package requires the `Rcpp` package to be installed. So first install the `Rcpp` package then deploy the app.

```
install.packages("Rcpp")
deployApp()
```

Uploaded successfully!

Comment: Thank you very much. Only it's "Rcpp", not "Rccp" :)