# Error Deploying Shiny App: Unhandled Exception: Invalid control character

Tags: r, web, shiny, publish

I have an app that works perfectly on my local computer. However, when I am trying to deploy a Shiny app to shinyapps.io, it doesn't work. I get the following error:

```
> deployApp()
Preparing to deploy application...DONE
Uploading bundle for application: 172259...DONE
Deploying bundle: 789393 for application: 172259 ...
Waiting for task: 373077993
  error: Parsing manifest
################################ Begin Task Log ################################ 
################################# End Task Log ################################# 
Error: Unhandled Exception: Child Task 373077994 error: Unhandled Exception: Invalid control character at: line 1495 column 8 (char 103196)
```

I am not sure what to do.

I have tried installing `Rcpp` as in this question, [An error in deploying shiny app to Shinyapps.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32824091/an-error-in-deploying-shiny-app-to-shinyapps-io), but that didn't work.

I have two other files besides ui.R and server.R in the directory, one CSV file that I read and one R object file (I previously used `save` to save something and then load it into R using `load` - just to save time). I have tried it with and without these files in the directory and it gives the same error either way.

I have a Mac and R is version 3.3.3. rsconnect is version 0.7.

Note that I found a similar problem here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shinyapps-users/Y5SNdQh5hKk but I am not sure of how to use this to help me.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to this post, https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/shinyapps-users/control$20character%7Csort:relevance/shinyapps-users/tMIi25WGFkw/90nTvt4LC18J, I was able to solve the problem by first showing all of the hidden files (see, for example http://osxdaily.com/2009/02/25/show-hidden-files-in-os-x/) and then deleting them, especially the icon file.